# Why does my low pass filter diverge below 7000 Hz?

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, stability, biquad

I'm trying to create a LPF, using language JAVA. My first aim is to understand how filters design is working and the second one is to create a "home made" equalizer with "home made" filters.
To help me, I'm using [EarLevel](http://www.earlevel.com/main/) website for the [formulas](http://www.earlevel.com/main/2011/01/02/biquad-formulas/) and to check my [calculations results](http://www.earlevel.com/main/2010/12/20/biquad-calculator/) for the feedforward / feedback coefficients ; and 
the [introduction to digital filters](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters/filters.html) by Julius O. Smith.
My input have is sampled at 44100 Hz and my Q=0.7071 (an approximation of 1/sqrt(2)) and I'm using the general formula :

$$y(n) = f_0 x(n) + f_1 x(n-1) + f_2 x(n-2)  
- b_1 y(n-1) - b_2 y(n-2)$$

with $f_0$ being the zeroth feed-forward coefficient, and so on, and $b_1$ being the first feed-back coefficient.
Edit : The coefficients are stored in a type "double".

In a first time, I set the center frequency at 10 000 Hz and it seems working. Then, I tried to lower the center frequency. When I reached around 7000 Hz, my output signal started to diverge after less than 30 "computations".

Here are my feedforward / feedback coefficients calculated for a 44100 Hz sampling signal with a central frenquency at 2000 Hz and Q = 0.7071 :

\begin{align}
f_0 &= 0.016819123361395717\\
f_1 &= 0.033638246722791434\\
f_2 &= 0.016819123361395717\\
b_1 &= -1.601089848140876\\
b_2 &= 0.668366341586459  
\end{align}

There are the same values thand those given by the site calculator so, I suppose they are correct.

But here is the input / output result after 20 signals sent to the filter :
Edit : The input datas are integers, representing the 16 bits input audio signal (from -32000 to +32000). The audio format used is a PCM_signed signal, sampled at 44100 Hz, 16 bits, 2 channels. I made test by comparison to check if the transformation PCM coded => integer => PCM coded was ok and, yes, it is ; so, the problem don't seems to come from there.
The output datas are stored in a double to keep the precision after the unit digit. Of course, I round them to an integer before sending them to the sound card.

> id = 20 - input = -2997 output= -4511.426234017688
>   id = 21 - input = -3022 output= 97.52810634470279
>   id = 22 - input = -3506 output= -6592.151428768328
>   id = 23 - input = -3176 output= 2949.256088740449
>   id = 24 - input = -3272 output= -10840.64632338293
>   id = 25 - input = -3287 output= 8909.22977931816
>   id = 26 - input = -2555 output= -19536.606226891832
>   id = 27 - input = -3123 output= 21316.24417688955
>   id = 28 - input = -1890 output= -37414.30445881503
>   id = 29 - input = -2821 output= 47023.28302742664
>   id = 30 - input = -1497 output= -74302.58304596202
>   id = 31 - input = -2557 output= 100154.15317482647
>   (...)
>   id = 45 - input = -3401 output= 1.6528078507359352E7
>   id = 46 - input = -2367 output= -2.3763232415918328E7
>   id = 47 - input = -3865 output= 3.415084117779622E7
>   (...)
>   id = 2047 - input = 1971 output= Infinity
>   id = 2048 - input = 4435 output= -Infinity
>   id = 2049 - input = 2648 output= Infinity

What's wrong ? Why does that signal diverge ? And why around 7000 Hz ? A LPF should work for much lower frequencies if I want to redirect it to a subwoofer for example, isn't it ?

Thank you for your help...

Edit[2](http://www.earlevel.com/main/2011/01/02/biquad-formulas/) : Here are the methods I'm using to find the coefficients and the method I'm using to calculate the output.

```
protected int centerFrequency, samplingFrequency;
protected double settingFactor;
protected double feedforward0, feedforward1, feedforward2, feedback1, feedback2;
protected double normalized, coefK;
private int test=0;

public LowPassFilter(int samplingFrequency, int centerFrequency, double qualityFactor) {
        super(samplingFrequency, centerFrequency, qualityFactor);
        coefK=Math.tan(Math.PI*centerFrequency/samplingFrequency);
        computeGains(settingFactor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void computeGains(double qualityFactor) {
        normalized= 1 / (1 + coefK / qualityFactor + coefK * coefK);
        feedforward0 = coefK * coefK * normalized;
        feedforward1 = 2 * feedforward0;
        feedforward2 = feedforward0;
        feedback1 = 2 * (coefK * coefK - 1) * normalized;
        feedback2 = (1 - coefK / qualityFactor + coefK * coefK) * normalized;
        System.out.println("LPF.computeGains : "+feedforward0+" ; "+feedforward1+" ; "+feedforward2+" ; "+feedback1+" ; "+feedback2);
    }
```

And here is the routine :

```
protected LinkedList<Integer> inputValues2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
protected LinkedList<Double> outputValues2 = new LinkedList<Double>();

public double process(int inputValue) {
        // On renseigne la valeur d'entrée dans le tableau des valeurs d'entrées
        inputValues2.removeFirst();
        inputValues2.add(inputValue);
        double outputValue= feedforward0*inputValues2.get(2) + feedforward1*inputValues2.get(1) + feedforward2*inputValues2.get(0) - feedback1*outputValues2.get(1) - feedback2*outputValues2.get(0);
        outputValues2.removeFirst();
        outputValues2.add(outputValue);
        if ((test>0 && test<100) || (test>2030 && test<2050)) {
            System.out.println("BiquadFilter.process - id = "+test+" - input = "+inputValues2.get(0)+" output= "+outputValues2.get(0)         );
        }
        test++;
        return outputValue;
    }
```

Comment: It's really cool that you're using a biquad, because it's a very mighty architecture for efficient implementation and hence widely used in audio processing, but it would be helpful to know what you're planning to *do* with that filter afterwards, to understand what you need.

Comment: also, I might be missing something, but what do your input and output values represent?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Marcus. I edited my post to explain my "plans". My input values are the 16 bit audio signal (from -32000 to +32000) and my output value is the audio signal after the filtering. I kept is with digits after the unity (and not converted to integer) to have a better precision.

Comment: 1 - What language are you using?

2 - What size are your variables. Inputs, outputs, coefficients, states. It is imperative to know.

Comment: but these are merely 47 samples then, @Dr_Click, how can you derive a low pass (or not low pass) behaviour from these? Where do your 7000  Hz appear here? I'm really a bit confused.

Comment: You can test your coefficients here : http://www.earlevel.com/main/2016/12/08/filter-frequency-response-grapher/  An alternative textbook for to design LPF is RBJ's AudioEQ cookbook - http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt

Comment: How do you compute the output from the input and the filter coefficients? Are you sure there's no bug in the filter computation?

Comment: @Ben : I edited my question to add the language used (JAVA) and the type of my datas.

Comment: @Marcus Müller : the "id" value was just a way for me to identify each input signal. So, it starts to "1" but it can goes to more than one billion after few minutes of reading...

Comment: @Mat L. : I compute the coefficients with the link given at the beginning in my post : http://www.earlevel.com/main/2011/01/02/biquad-formulas/  The input is given by my sound file (I edited my question to give the audio format). The output is calculated with the formula y(n) = (...) wrotten in my question.

Comment: @Juha P : I'm also used the earlevel.com website to test my coefficients (link at the beginning of my post) and it seemed correct. I also tried the other earlevel.com link you gave me and, well, my coefficient are graphically giving me the expected answer on that website too. I will try to calculate them with the audioEQ cookbook to see if there is any difference...

Comment: Oups, my BIG MISTAKE : the calculated coefficients are for a center frequency at  2000 Hz (and not 7000). But everything else was right and, at 2000 Hz like at a previous test at 7000 Hz, I have that problem of divergent signal... :-(

Comment: @Dr_Click: When you say the output is computed according to the formula, then that's what you *think* it is. But how do you actually do it? There *must* be an error in your filtering routine, but as long as you don't show it to us, we cannot help you.

Comment: Perhaps you swapped the two feedback coefficients in your recurrence computation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this in Octave/Matlab:

```
a = [1,-1.601089848140876,0.668366341586459];
b = [0.016819123361395717,0.033638246722791434,0.016819123361395717];
r = roots(a);
abs(r)
ans =

   0.81754
   0.81754
```

Since the roots are all inside the unit circle, your filter is stable.

The magnitude response looks like it should for a Butterworth filter. However, as you've noticed yourself, for $f_s=44100$ Hz, the $3$-dB cut-off frequency is $2000$ Hz:

[image]

I conclude that the problem does not come from the filter coefficients. You should show us your filtering routine, because if there is no silly input/output problem, then the problem *must* be in the filtering routine. Even though you say you just implemented the recursion shown in your question, believe me that I've seen lots of buggy filter implementations. As long as you don't show your implementation, nobody can really help you find the problem.

It should also be easy enough to use any free software package (Octave/SciPy/etc.) with the same input and the same filter coefficients, and compare the outputs. This will convince you (if still necessary) that the problem is not caused by the coefficients.

You could perform a first simple check of your routine by computing the impulse response, using an impulse as the input signal (i.e., a `1` followed by zeros). In Octave/Matlab you can find the impulse response using the command `impz` (given the coefficients `a` and `b` from above):

```
h = impz(b,a);
```

The figure below shows the first $60$ values of the impulse response. Clearly, the filter is stable.

[image]

The first $15$ values of the impulse response are

```
   0.0168191
   0.0605672
   0.1025513
   0.1237127
   0.1295334
   0.1247092
   0.1130948
   0.0977236
   0.0808754
   0.0641737
   0.0486934
   0.0350710
   0.0236068
   0.0143563
   0.0072078
```

Comment: Thank you for that first answer. I will try Octave / Matlab this week-end. I edited my question and added the routine I'm using to calculate my output. Do you see something wrong in it ? That's often true that I don't see my own errors while they would be obvious for a third-part reader...

Comment: @Dr_Click: You should use an impulse as input (a single value of 1 and then only zeros), and see what the output is. It should be the filter's impulse response, and it is easy to check if it's correct.

Comment: I wrote a method to get the impulse response of my filter. But, how to know if the result is correct ? Is there a special site ? Or do I have to compare in MathLab / Octave ?

Comment: @Dr_Click: I added some info about the impulse response to my answer; use those to check your result.

Comment: Ok, I don't get the same impulse result. You are right, there is (more than) probably a mistake in my routine. When you read my code, did you fond something weird or a mistake ?

Comment: Ok, I don't get the same impulse result. You are right, there is (more than) probably a mistake in my routine. When you read my code, did you fond something weird or a mistake ?

Comment: Matt L., you were right : the mistake was in the routine. I considered "outputValues.get(1)" as my [y-1] but it was wrong. The last output is "outputValues.get(0)" as my current output is still not computed...  Thank you very much for the time you spent on my question. You were very helpful ! :-D

Comment: @Dr_Click: You're welcome, great that you found the mistake yourself!